# How to save entire stdout to variable using pexpect

Tags: python, io, pexpect

I’m using pexpect to run a Terminal command that outputs a relatively long block of text when run in the Terminal. The problem is how to get the full stdout saved to a variable, so that I can process it in my CLI program after the command ends.

I've tried:

```py
output = pexpect.run("[command]")
print(output.decode("utf-8"))
```

This only outputs one line from the command.

I've also tried:

```py
child = pexpect.spawn("[command]", 
            timeout=None,
            encoding="utf-8")
child.expect(pexpect.EOF)
with open('test.txt', 'w') as o: 
    o.write(child.before)
```

The printed output is some blank newlines — less than the full text length — but the generated file `test.txt` contains what looks like time stamps and an array-like string on each line:

```
[1m[36m⠏[0m [the line's output][0m
```

I don’t want these time stamps or the array-like formatting. How can I get the plain text stdout formatted as a string and saved as a variable?

Answer (score 0):

Those are [ANSI escape codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code). I think your command is trying to print something in bold (`[1m`), with the first character in cyan (`[36m`), and then using `[0m`'s to clear the formatting. Try this to remove the sequences:

**NOTE** - Tested using Ubuntu 20.04 and Python 3.8

```
import re

import pexpect

test = b'\x1b[32mwhich ls: /usr/bin/ls\x1b[0m\r\n\x1b[32mwhoami: stack\x1b[0m\r\n\x1b[31;1mCannot execute command find foo: /usr/bin/find: \xe2\x80\x98foo\xe2\x80\x99: No such file or directory\x1b[0m\r\n\x1b[32mdate: Sun 30 Jan 2022 11:53:37 PM EST\x1b[0m\r\n'

# Show raw output
print(test)
# Show formatted output
print(test.decode('utf-8'))
# Remove ANSI escape sequences and print
remove_ansi = re.compile(r'(\x9B|\x1B\[)[0-?]*[ -/]*[@-~]')
print(remove_ansi.sub('', str(test.decode('utf-8'))))

# Your script goes here
command_output = pexpect.run('[command')
print(remove_ansi.sub('', str(command_output.decode('utf-8'))))
```